# How to use OR condition for icontains in multiple fields with graphene-django

Tags: python, django, graphql, graphene-python, graphene-django

I have the following model in Django:

```py
class JobPost(models.Model):
    company = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=30, null=True)
    job = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=30, null=True)
    category = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=30, null=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, max_length=500, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.job
```

And I have the following schema with graphene:

```py
class JobPostNode(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        # Assume you have an Animal model defined with the following fields
        model = JobPost
        filter_fields = {
            'company': ['exact', 'icontains', 'istartswith'],
            'job': ['exact', 'icontains', 'istartswith'],
            'category': ['exact', 'icontains', 'istartswith'],
            "description": ['exact', 'icontains', 'istartswith'],
        }
        interfaces = (relay.Node,)


class Query(graphene.ObjectType):

    job = relay.Node.Field(JobPostNode)
    all_jobs = DjangoFilterConnectionField(JobPostNode)


schema = graphene.Schema(query=Query)
```

I want to use `icontains` whereas I will get data based on an OR not on AND; for example the following query:

```
{
  allJobs(job_Icontains: "t", company_Icontains: "v") {
    edges {
      node {
        company
        job
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Should return data that has the letter "t" in job OR the letter "v" in company, not the letter "t" in job AND the letter "v" in company. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out how to do this [here](https://www.howtographql.com/graphql-python/7-filtering/)! For my schema I wrote this:

```py
import graphene
from api_rest.models import JobPost
from django.db.models import Q
from graphene_django import DjangoObjectType


class JobType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = JobPost


class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    jobs = graphene.List(
        JobType, search=graphene.String(), first=graphene.Int(), skip=graphene.Int()
    )

    def resolve_jobs(self, info, search=None, first=None, skip=None, **kwargs):
        queryset = JobPost.objects.all()
        if search:
            filter = (
                Q(company__icontains=search)
                | Q(description__icontains=search)
                | Q(category__icontains=search)
            )
            queryset = queryset.filter(filter)

        if skip:
            queryset = queryset[skip:]

        if first:
            queryset = queryset[:first]
        return queryset


schema = graphene.Schema(query=Query)
```

Now, using the following query, I am getting the results I want:

```
{
  jobs(search: "transpo") {
    id
    company
    category
    job
    createdAt
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that works, but please add [indexes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#db-index) to your fields or else your site will slow to a crawl when it gets some real data volume.

Comment: Thank you @Melvyn, I think it is set automatically by Django in my case. I see the IDs for each record in my database. It should be cool no?